# Parsing .ssh/config for proxy information

Tags: regex, perl, bash, sed, awk

I would like to parse the `.ssh/config` file for proxy information contained therein and display each host that has related proxy information with the proxy information. Hosts that do not have any proxy information should be filtered out. Man page for `.ssh/config`: http://man-wiki.net/index.php/5:ssh_config

This should be done from a Unix shell script under Bash, so a standard tool like Perl, awk or sed is preferred.

Example input file:

```
Host ssh.foo.com
    User ssh
    HostName ssh.foo.com
    Port 443
    ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy 8080 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth

Host ci
    HostName 127.0.0.2
    User ci

Host nightly
    HostName 192.168.1.1
    User goodnight

Host foobar.org
    User git
    HostName foobar.org
    Port 443
    ProxyCommand /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy 8080 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth

Host integration
    HostName 192.168.1.2
    User int
```

The expected output should look like this:

```
Host: ssh.foo.com - Proxy: /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy 8080 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth
Host: foobar.org - Proxy: /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy 8080 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth
```

The difficulty here is that the search has to cover multiple lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try following `awk` command:

```
awk '
    $1 == "Host" { 
        host = $1 ": " $2; 
        next; 
    } 
    $1 == "ProxyCommand" { 
        $1 = ""; 
        sub( /^[[:space:]]*/, "" ); 
        printf "%s - Proxy: %s\n", host, $0;
    }
' .ssh/config
```

It yields:

```
Host: ssh.foo.com - Proxy: /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy 8080 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth
Host: foobar.org - Proxy: /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy 8080 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth
```

Answer (score 2):

an awk oneliner may work for your requirement:

```
awk -v RS="" '/Proxy/{gsub(/\n/,"");gsub(/\s*User.*ProxyCommand/,"- Proxy:");print}'file
```

**test** (a.txt is your input file)

```
kent$  awk -v RS="" '/Proxy/{gsub(/\n/,"");gsub(/\s*User.*ProxyCommand/,"- Proxy:");print}' a.txt                                                                  
Host ssh.foo.com    - Proxy: /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy 8080 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth
Host foobar.org    - Proxy: /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy 8080 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for kicks, here is a nasty sed command that seems to accomplish this.

```
sed -n '/^[Hh]ost/{:r;h;:l;n;/^[Hh]ost/!{/[Pp]roxy/H;bl};/^[Hh]ost/{x;/[Pp]roxy/{s/\n\s*/ - /;s/[Cc]ommand/:/;s/[Hh]ost/\0:/;p};x;br}}' ~/.ssh/config
```

This is more for demonstration purposes anyway since the other solutions are much easier to grasp.  A commented view of this:

```
/^[Hh]ost/ {                # Begin on a Host line
    :restart                # Label to jump back to
    h                       # Copy the pattern space to the save space
    :loop                   # Label to jump to when we don't want to wipe out the save space
    n                       # Read in the next line
    /^[Hh]ost/!{            # For lines that aren't host definitions
        /[Pp]roxy/H         # If they are proxy configurations, append the line to the save space
        b loop              # Go to :loop
    }
    /^[Hh]ost/{             # If they are *not* host definitions
        x                   # Exchange the pattern and save spaces
        /[Pp]roxy/{         # If the new pattern space contains a proxy configuration
            s/\n\s*/ - /    # Insert the required separator
            s/[Cc]ommand/:/ # Change "ProxyCommand" to "Proxy:"
            s/[Hh]ost/\0:/  # Change "Host" to "Host:"
            p               # Print the pattern space
        }
        x                   # Exchange the pattern and save spaces
        b restart           # Go to :restart
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
Host: ssh.foo.com - Proxy: /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy 8080 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth
Host: foobar.org - Proxy: /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy 8080 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out the [Net::SSH::Perl::Config](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SSH-Perl/lib/Net/SSH/Perl/Config.pm) module ? It claims to read configs in the standard `ssh` format - albeit with a subset of keywords.

> The configuration files should be in the same format used for the ssh
>   command line program; see the ssh manpage for information on this
>   format. Net::SSH::Perl::Config understands a subset of the
>   configuration directives that can live in these files; this subset
>   matches up with the functionality that Net::SSH::Perl can support.
>   Unknown keywords will simply be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

One way using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -nre '/^Host/h;/ProxyCommand/{H;x;s/(Host)(.*)\n +[^ ]+ /\1:\2 - Proxy: /p}' file.txt
```

Results:

```
Host: ssh.foo.com - Proxy: /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy 8080 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth
Host: foobar.org - Proxy: /usr/local/bin/corkscrew proxy 8080 %h %p ~/.ssh/proxyauth
```

Comment: Very nice.  I am now ashamed of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open FD, "DATA" || die $!;
my $line = do {local $/; <FD>};
my @a = split /Host\b/, $line;
foreach (@a) {
    if (defined $_ and /^\s*(\S+).*ProxyCommand\s+([^\n]+)/s) {
        print "$1 - Proxy: $2\n";
    }   
}
```